# If I have money, do I need formal education to foster my publications?

Tags: publications, mathematics, degree, education, non-degree

I suffered religious discrimination and didn't finish my university study. As a result, I (meanwhile) continuing scientific research on my own. Some mis-published (*published in a wrong venue" or not enough reputable or not popular publisher in the field*), some key results (in abstract mathematics).
I'll say I'm "covering" scientific result instead of discovering: as nobody other participates in my scientific program not presented by a degree holder.

Today I got good conversion rate for my nonprofit's fundraising. It appears that very soon my nonprofit will have enough money to pay for a degree program for me.

Should I get a degree to foster my research, or should I have this mindset: "For money I can make my research into Scopus, I don't need a degree."?

Note that I hardly need university study for study. As doing research on my own (with some advices of other scientists in forums sometimes) is working well enough without overhead of somebody paying to advisors. I have the problem not in research but in publication.

Comment: So you published incorrect results and you conclude that you don’t need better training to do better research , you just need help publishing?

Comment: Also, you should not be using nonprofit funds for your personal degree unless that is what you told your donors you would be using the money for. Using the funds for your own self-interest would be fraud.

Comment: @Dawn What caused you to conclude that my results are incorrect? Getting myself degree is well-agreed with the stated purpose of my nonprofit, so no, it is not a fraud. And yes, I tell it to donors that I use money this way.

Comment: You said you “mis-published” the results. Honestly, it was very difficult to understand your question as your English is not standard.

Comment: @Dawn By "mis-published” I mean "published in a wrong venue" / not enough reputable or popular publisher.

Comment: You can't buy authorship if that's what you mean.

Comment: Could you kindly clarify ... "*covering" scientific result instead of discovering: as nobody other participates in my scientific program not presented by a degree holder.*"

Comment: By *didn't finish my university study*, are you implying not finishing first degree (UG)

Comment: @semmyk-research It means that I deprived PhD of the desire to keep building on my research (even if it would be rediscovered), because every PhD wants to work in an established scientific school not on a work of an amateur: https://science.vporton.name/2021/11/03/how-modern-scientific-ethic-may-block-a-science/

Comment: What do you mean “to foster your publications”?

Comment: @Dawn to increase reach and perceived credibility of my publications. I also want to make others interested in it and join my research project.

Comment: @semmyk-research Yes, I didn't finish Bachelor

Comment: What does money have to do with fostering your publications? Seems completely unrelated, unless you exclusively submit to OA journals or if you hire a publicist to publicize your results. In the same way getting a degree also seems completely unrelated to fostering your publications.

Comment: @Allure I would like to get a book publication grant.

Comment: If you have money why do you need a grant?

Comment: @Allure That's the question, does degree provide other benefits than these grants?

Comment: I would suggest rewriting the question entirely then (or maybe even writing a new one, since this one looks very different from what you're actually asking).

Answer (score 1):

I would have said, if your publications are notable and not in '*predatory*' journals, you could aim for PhD by Publication (retrospective route). However, that won't be applicable as you'll struggle (almost mission impossible) because you don't have a first degree.
With a degree (at least) and some credible publications and [your book](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/51885/i-have-made-my-independent-research-available-as-a-book-on-my-website-why-is-it) published as well, you might make a proper shot with recognised university (without the risk of *[diploma mill](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23406/is-a-university-that-grants-me-a-phd-for-1000-and-a-copy-of-my-unpublished-book)*).

> Should I get a degree to foster my research,

A degree to *foster* your research is not compulsory, however, it would be highly helpful.
You can also foster your research capabilities by *working* in a research environment/post. Of course, [do research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/196027/can-someone-without-a-doctorate-or-an-undergraduate-degree-do-research/196047#196047) is possible in some other (limited) ways. Having a degree and continuing doing research (*amateurs*, independent) is [recommended](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/196031/162770).

> or should I have this mindset: "For money I can make my research into Scopus, I don't need a degree."?

This is a dangerous mindset. Research and research publications aren't all about money. Even if publishing in Scopus indexed journal, you still need to carry out research, be involved in research, contribute to knowledge.

I take note that some might [fund/set up research centers/institute](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/195910/162770).

PS: ...*I don't need a degree*... might be subjective depending on individual. This, I think, might be beyond the scope of Academia. However, for the reason you provided, and that your not-for-profit is aimed at obtaining a degree, then aim for the degree and also continue on the path of research.
You might want to take a [look here as well](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/192439/how-to-view-undergraduate-studies-in-maths) although on a different topic.